# Why stepping over the SCrypt.generate() (Bouncy Castle Java API) line using breakpoint(Eclipse) blocks the debugging process?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, bouncycastle, scrypt

I keep pressing **F6** in eclipse during debugging

```
public void method() {   
Line 54: --------My breakpoint is here------
Line 55: -------Some line of code----- 

Line 56: byte[] sCryptHash1  = SCrypt.generate(plaintextPassword.getBytes(),  salt.getBytes(), 16384, 8, 1, 16);    

--------Some more lines of code----- 
}
```

When debugger line reached line 56, debugging gets blocked, does not proceed/respond, I will have to terminate the debugging.

What is the reason for such behavior ? Is it because of the SCrypt.generate method ?

I am using Bouncy Castle Java API for hashing.

If I don't use breakpoint on that line everything executes successfully.

Comment: you need to press `f5` to step into `SCrypt.generate` call to see why execution is blocking

Comment: It still gets blocked.

Comment: sometimes, debuging slows down the process, so may be u have to wait longer ?

Comment: Yes its slowing down, but without breakpoint its very fast.

Comment: The whole point of scrypt is to slow down the generation of keys from passwords. If you run it in a debugger it will be very slow indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find out if the process is really hanging or just be very slow you can connect a profiler to the process and check what the process is currently doing. If you don't have a profile you can dump the thread dump and check the corresponding stacktrace.

The latter can be done on Windows systems by pressing CTRL-Break in the console the process is running (in case of Eclipse that's the output console). On Linux or other Unix-like systems you can dump it by sending a `kill -3 [PID of the Java process]`. The dump then goes to STDOUT of the Java process.